# Tenses in Genesis 2:4-7

Tags: genesis, translation-philosophy, textual-criticism

There seems to be a lot of variation between the way tenses are used in this passage between translations. For example:

> <sup>**4**</sup> These are the generations of the heavens and of the earth when they were created, in the day that the Lord God made the earth and the heavens, <sup>**5**</sup> And every plant of the field before it was in the earth, and every herb of the field before it grew: for the Lord God had not caused it to rain upon the earth, and there was not a man to till the ground. <sup>**6**</sup> But there went up a mist from the earth, and watered the whole face of the ground. <sup>**7**</sup> And the Lord God formed man of the dust of the ground, and breathed into his nostrils the breath of life; and man became a living soul. (KJV)

Whereas the NLT translates this passage as:

> <sup>**4**</sup> This is the account of the creation of the heavens and the earth. When the Lord God made the earth and the heavens, <sup>**5**</sup> neither wild plants nor grains were growing on the earth. For the Lord God had not yet sent rain to water the earth, and there were no people to cultivate the soil. <sup>**6**</sup> Instead, springs came up from the ground and watered all the land. <sup>**7**</sup> Then the Lord God formed the man from the dust of the ground. He breathed the breath of life into the man’s nostrils, and the man became a living person. (NLT)

This subtle change is significant because people argue on the basis of translations like the KJV that there are two contradicting accounts in Genesis 1 and 2 whereas, translations like the NLT reconcile the two accounts.

I would consider it odd if an editor put together the two accounts, and edited them so that you get strong links (e.g. God names everything except animals in the first one, God makes man in his image, God gets man to name animals in the second one), but forgot to edit out a contradiction around timeline (in Genesis 1, plants are created before man, in some translations it appears that they were created afterward).

- Is there any basis for the usage of past tense in Hebrew for translating the passage in the way the NLT does?
- When we look at ancient translations like the Targums and LXX, do they translate it in a way that presents a contradiction like the KJV or a harmony like the NLT?

Comment: I am struggling to understand the contradiction you point to.  What is your problem?  Hebrew does not have verb tenses, BTW.  Gen 1 & 2 present two separate creation accounts that emphasize different aspects of the story.

Comment: As Dottard has explained, there is no contradiction, at all.

Comment: You claim that "This subtle change is significant because people argue on the basis of translations like the KJV that there are two contradicting accounts in Genesis 1 and 2..." Where is there evidence for that? The 2 accounts of Creation teach different lessons, both sets of which are needed to grasp the full impact of Creation. Who claims that the sets are contradictory?